# Logarithm Calculation

Tags: logarithms

It was part of my graph theory homework solution. The topic was about random graphs. I have difficulty understanding one step about log calculation. Hope someone could help me answer this:
$\frac{\log(1-\frac{c\log n}{n})}{-\frac{c\log n}{n}}\cdot\frac{-c\log n}{n}(n-1)=\log n^{-(1+o(1))c}$. Here in this problem, the $o(1)$ notation is in terms of  $n$.

Appreciate if you could answer it!

Comment: It is called "o" notation.  Google it up!

Comment: that "o" notation I know. my problem is about the log calculation.

Comment: You could take the exponent out of the RHS using logarithmic rules.